# Python raw_input("") error

Tags: python, windows, python-2.6, raw-input

I am writing a simple commandline script that uses raw_input, but it doesn't seem to work.

This code:

```
print "Hello!"
raw_input("")
```

Produces this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<pyshell#6>", line 1, in <module>
raw_input("")
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

I have never encountered this error before, and couldn't find anything on Google. I am using Python 2.6 on Windows 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears you are using something called `pyshell`. There is likely a bug there in that shell itself. Try just using vanilla bash.

Comment: I think it was some sort of bug. I closed all the processes associated with the interpreter and editor, then ran it again and it worked just fine. Thank you everyone for your suggestions though! :)

Answer (score 2):

Works fine as presented, e.g. in an interpreter prompt in any Python 2 version:

```
>>> print "Hello!"
Hello!
>>> raw_input("")
bah
'bah'
>>>
```

where `bah` is what I typed *after* the code you gave in response to the empty-prompt;-).

The *only* explanation for the error you mention is that you've performed *other* code before this, which included binding identifier `raw_input` to a string.